# How does a ComboBox decide what text will be shown for an Item?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

It's all in the title. A `ComboBox` is populated by an `IEnumerable` of type `SomeType`. How does the `ComboBox` decide what text will be shown for each Item?

Of course I'm not asking about cases where the type is `string`.

Comment: @Babbillumpa Thanks. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @ispiro *you* specify using data binding. If there are no data binding expressions specified, it falls back to `ToString()`

Comment: @ispiro someone has preceded me. :D

Comment: @Babbillumpa `ToString()` is the fallback, not the common usage.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i know.... However, in order to avoid misunderstandings, i removed the comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have defined an `ItemTemplate`, this one is being applied to all items returned by the `IEnumerable`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="custom..." />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

If not, you will see the `ToString()` representation of each item. You can confirm this by overriding the `ToString()` method of your data type.

You can also set the `DisplayMemberPath` property of the `ComboBox` to a name of a public property of your data type. Then the value of this property will be displayed instead of the value of `ToString()`.

Comment: Do not forget to mention DisplayMemberPath.

Comment: @Clemens: Thanks. I edited my answer to include the  DisplayMemberPath option.